# What could cause IIS logs with time-taken of 29641895 milliseconds

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, logparser

For few thousand requests in a log of more than 2 million records, IIS is recording time-taken as 29641895 or similar large numbers. The time-taken value is in milliseconds, so when converted to hours, it translates to almost 8 hours. What could be causing such logs in IIS?

The logs being looked at are for a ASP.NET 4.0 web application hosted on a IIS 7+, Windows 2008 server. The application is developed on top of ASP.NET MVC 3 framework.

The logs are present for computed requests and for static requests also.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.winserverkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/iis/13210/Very-large-value-for-Time-taken-in-IIS-log-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASP.NET MVC 3 doesn't apply the "executionTimeout" attribute in the web.config file.  So you may suffer the long running log entry for that reason.  Please check this post: [Bug in MVC3 - requests never time out.  Works fine for aspx pages in same project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198267/bug-in-mvc3-requests-never-time-out-works-fine-for-aspx-pages-in-same-project)

Comment: Thanks for linking this to your post. I also saw your post on ASP.NET MVC's forums. I hope the same is fixed in the next version.