# Bug in MVC3 - requests never time out.  Works fine for aspx pages in same project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, timeout

I'm seeing this on our production site as well as a small test site I setup just to test this out...

Basically, it appears that requests handled by mvc never time out.  I've set an executionTimeout in my web.config and turned off debug mode.  I've then added an infinite loop of thread.sleeps to both a regular aspx page and an mvc page (the loop is in the controller of the mvc page).  The aspx page reliably times out (HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out.), but the mvc page just spins forever without timing out.

Are there separate settings for mvc (I've looked but haven't found them)?  Do mvc requests not timeout by default?

Any help on this would be appreciated.  I'll gladly email out my small test site if it would help anyone out.

Edit: I'm using MVC3.

Contents of my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="16384" executionTimeout="30" />
      <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
          <assemblies>
          <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
          <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
          <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
          <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
          <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
          </assemblies>
      </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This is happening to me too!! I'm surprised i haven't seen anyone else complain about this issue!

Comment: whats the point of this? Does it actually ever happen in real scenario?

Comment: have you ever found a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the cause for this, methinks:

This method is in the WrappedAsyncResult class, which the MvcHandler class uses via BeginProcessRequest:

```
public static IAsyncResult BeginSynchronous<TResult>(AsyncCallback callback, object state, Func<TResult> func, object tag)
{
    BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate = delegate (AsyncCallback asyncCallback, object asyncState) {
        SimpleAsyncResult result = new SimpleAsyncResult(asyncState);
        result.MarkCompleted(true, asyncCallback);
        return result;
    };
    EndInvokeDelegate<TResult> endDelegate = _ => func();
    WrappedAsyncResult<TResult> result = new WrappedAsyncResult<TResult>(beginDelegate, endDelegate, tag);
    result.Begin(callback, state, -1);
    return result;
}
```

where "Begin" is:

```
public void Begin(AsyncCallback callback, object state, int timeout)
{
    bool completedSynchronously;
    this._originalCallback = callback;
    lock (this._beginDelegateLockObj)
    {
        this._innerAsyncResult = this._beginDelegate(new AsyncCallback(this.HandleAsynchronousCompletion), state);
        completedSynchronously = this._innerAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously;
        if (!completedSynchronously && (timeout > -1))
        {
            this.CreateTimer(timeout);
        }
    }
    if (completedSynchronously && (callback != null))
    {
        callback(this);
    }
}
```

EDIT: have come up with a ham-handed way of forcing MVC controller actions to "time out", although the mechanism is a bit brutish:

```
public class TimeoutController : Controller
{
    private bool _isExecuting = false;
    private int _controllerTimeout = 5000;
    private Thread _executingThread;
    private readonly object _syncRoot = new object();

    protected override void ExecuteCore()
    {
        _executingThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(_controllerTimeout);
                if (_isExecuting)
                {
                    _executingThread.Abort();
                }
            });
        base.ExecuteCore();
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        _isExecuting = true;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        _isExecuting = false;                
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }

    public int ControllerTimeout
    {
        get
        {
            int retVal;
            lock(_syncRoot)
            {
                retVal = _controllerTimeout;
            }
            return retVal;
        }
        set
        {
            lock(_syncRoot)
            {
                _controllerTimeout = value;                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain where, how and what is the ControllerTimeout doing?

Comment: Basically, it forces the thread executing the controller to abort after a specified timeout period; kind of like burning your house down to kill a spider.

Comment: Microsoft says to use the ScriptTimeout instead.
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/781171/asp-net-mvc-executiontimeout-does-not-work

Answer (score 2):

It should work when these conditions are met:

1) Domain name is not localhost (to test timeout you should use "YourComputerName" instead of "localhost").

2) Project is compiled in Release mode.

3) compilation debug="false"

if not look here for an alternative (ScriptTimeOut):
[ASP.NET MVC and httpRuntime executionTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492346/asp-net-mvc-and-httpruntime-executiontimeout)

Greetings,
Daddy

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't seem to have fixed the issue.

I'm now using my computer's name rather than localhost, I compiled it in release mode in visual studio and have debug set to false in my web.config.

I've also tried setting the scriptTimeout property on my mvc pages but that hasn't helped either.  I think this might be a bug in the framework.

Comment: You have seen the remark in the other SO thread about not having a ~ in the path? Maybe that's your problem. I agree that it should work in debug though.

Comment: I'm not using the location tag, so there is no path.  I just want this timeout to work on a global level for mvc and aspx pages.  With my current setup it works fine for aspx pages, but mvc pages won't timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Still happening for me in MVC 4.  I have submitted this to microsoft as a bug:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/781171/asp-net-mvc-executiontimeout-does-not-work

Update:

Microsoft commented with the following:

> The execution timeout feature is not advised to be used in MVC
>   applications. You can instead set HttpContext.Server.ScriptTimeout to
>   the desired timeout value. Despite the name, this is a per-request
>   setting and should apply to any ASP.NET request (the name "script" is
>   misleading)

.